# How to remove white spaces while comparing array lists

Tags: java, selenium, automation

```
//View Company-View Project

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> rows10 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p|//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/p|//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div/p|//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[1]/div[7]/div/p|//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[1]/div[8]/div/p|//*[@class='content- 
wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div/p"));
List<String> all_elements_text10 = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<rows10.size(); i++) {
  all_elements_text10.add(rows10.get(i).getText());
  System.out.println(rows10.get(i).getText());
}

List<WebElement> rows11 = driver.findElements(By.xpath ("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[9]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div/p|/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/p"));
List<String> all_elements_text11 = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<rows11.size(); i++) {
  all_elements_text11.add(rows11.get(i).getText());
  System.out.println(rows11.get(i).getText());
 }

Assert.assertEquals(all_elements_text10, all_elements_text11);
System.out.println("All Dropdown Fields matched in View Company-Project");


}
```

Here i am comparing the two array lists. By executing the above code i got the below error.The second array list is having one space.How can i remove that white space and compare the lists.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Lists differ at element [3]: Selenium != Selenium  expected [Selenium] but found [Selenium ]
```

Comment: You can take all elements from arraylist and do like this `st = st.replaceAll("\\s+","")`

Comment: add `trim()` to `rows10.get(i).getText()` and `rows11.get(i).getText()`

Comment: @ Anton Balaniuc  - I got the same error even after adding trim().I have modified like this  - all_elements_text10.add(rows10.get(i).getText().trim());

Comment: @ raul1ro - How can take all elements from arraylist can you please elaborate

Comment: @Anton Balaniuc - adding trim() solved my error.Previously i have tried it on a wrong code.Now it's working fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
rows10.get(i).getText().replaceAll("\\s+", "") 

rows11.get(i).getText().replaceAll("\\s+", "")
```

Hope this help!